# Extracting korean and numeric characters

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract Korean letters before '로' and before '길'in that WORD using regex.
Also I need to extract numbers associated after these special characters.

```
장안로458번길 138 -> extract "장안", corresponding 458 number and "번", 138
충서로 1600       -> extract "충서", 1600
```

This regex `\p{L}+?(?=로|길)` works for the characters. How do we extend the same regex to extract numbers too?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not", please try to find a more meaningful title for your question!

Answer (score 4):

This should work for your case:

```
(\p{L}+?)(?:로|길)\s*(\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lD5hT1/1)

`\s*(\d+)` ignores spaces and captures a number after the character. The parts to extract are in groups 1 and 2 (`match.Groups[1].Value` contains the characters, `match.Groups[2].Value` contains the number).